# Regular Expression allow a decimal with up to 3 characters or integer with up to 2 characters

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to write a regex for a RegularExpressionValidator Control that will allow a decimal or integer with the following conditions:

- Cannot be negative and zero.
- Maximum string length including the optional decimal point is 3 characters and if only integers entered then 2 characters
- Maximum number of decimal places is 1

So these are good....

```
0.1,
0.9,
9.0,
9.1,
2,
34
```

and these are bad.....

```
 0,
-0,
-1,
-0.1,
.1,
.34,
 9.01,
 9.12,
345
```

Could you please help me out. I have looked at so many Regex samples but not able to build the right one which matches the above conditions.

Comment: What language are you writing in? What have you done so far? Which of the cases you wrote is it failing on?

Comment: In Regex syntax..like as below                                                         (?!^0[1-9])(?=^([0-9])+(\.\d{1,2}(?<!0))?$)^.{1,7}$

Comment: 9.0, 9.1, 9.2 should be allowed but not 9.01, 9.34 and 9.

Comment: Do you really have to do everything in the regexp? Can't you do regexp first and then numeric checks after? That way you don't have to filter out all the different forms of zero in the regexp, 0, 0.0, 00. 0., 00.

Comment: Allowing 0.1 but not .1 sounds like terrible design.  If this is something a user needs to interact with, why not be sane and just convert the string into a number then check it there.

Comment: I am using the Asp.Net Regular expression validation control, so I thought to do everything in regexp.

Comment: You, just now: "I am using the Asp.Net Regular expression validation control, so I thought to do everything in regexp."
Jamie Zawinski, sixteen years ago: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."  Now they have two problems."
Your situation illustrates his point perfectly. The regex-only solution you came up with looks like it will work, but it is very complex and nigh-impossible to maintain (good luck figuring out what that regex does when you reread your code in six months!). The other solution (simple regex, then test non-zero) is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and come out with the below regex expression..which satisfies all the good values and bad values mentioned in the question.

```
^(([1-9])|([0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([0-9][.][1-9])|([1-9][.][0-9]))$
```

I don't have much knowledge on regex, looking at some samples written the above regex found working fine. Please let me know your feedback on this, whether above regex can be written in this way and will it have any performance issues and if any other.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regexp:

```
^(\d{1,2}\.?|\d\.\d)$
```

The first alternative allows 2-digit integer with an optional decimal point, the second allows a digit followed by 1 decimal place.

If it passes this validation, then test it against:

```
[^0]
```

to ensure it's not zero.